# VS Web Setup Project alternatives?

Tags: asp.net, setup-project, web-setup-project

Can anyone recommend a better installer for **web-applications**? What do you use to deploy/install your web-apps?

PS. What I personally dislike about "Web Setup Project" is that it requires the "IIS 6.0 Management Capability Feature" to be present on the target machine. This frustrates many of our customers.

Answer (score 3):

I've used Advanced Installer in the past and it worked well for me. The IIS features are in the Pro edition or above, which makes it pretty cheap as well ($299 for Pro).

http://www.advancedinstaller.com/internet-information-services.html